# Python does not show help for append

Tags: python, append

I am super new to coding and started with python.
To know how to search for help would already massively help me
Here my question:
Why can I not find any help in the interpreter for the 'append()' function?

I am sorry, I know this is basic.

Comment: Because it doesn't exist.

Comment: Because there's no such function. `append` is a **method** of `list` class. Therefore you need to use `help(list.append)`…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `help('list.append')` or `help(list.append)`

```
help('list.append')
```

output:

```
Help on method_descriptor in list:

list.append = append(self, object, /)
    Append object to the end of the list.
```

---

also you could check the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)